# Why is the height size of a renderObject for a Text Widget bigger than the fontSize

Tags: flutter, widget, height, font-size, text-widget

Consider having this simple Text Widget:

```
Text(
    product.name,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
)
```

When I inspect the Widget tree inside Flutter Inspector I see that the renderObject has a size with the height of 19.
Also, for a fontSize = 14 the value for the renderObject height size is 16.

How is this 19(for fontSize 16) or 16(for fontSize 14) value calculated?

I see that the browsers(Chrome at least) do a similar thing and I noticed that `line-height` CSS property does this, having a value around 1.166667.

Going back to Flutter I noticed that the actual rendereBox height value is `fontSize*lineHeight` rounded (which is around 1.166667 too).

I tried setting the `height` of the `TextStyle` to 1([which seems it is the same](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) as the CSS property) but with no luck. The `TextStyle` `height` property has a default value of 1 already, not 1.166667.

Where can I get the exact value of this lineHeight? How is ti calculated if it is not hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: Did you find out why?

Comment: @A.Ktns this was a long time ago. I don't remember anymore. I think we just did some manual subtracting back then

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `height` property of the `TextStyle` and set to zero, like this:

```
          Text(
               product.name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  height: 0
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: The text is rendered but the render box has a height of 0 now, not 16(for fontSize 16). Also, because of this, the text appears to overflow the TextWidget making it appear on top of the Widget above it.